# how compensate the rest row in one matrix from knowing the second

Tags: matlab

if i have

A=[1;2;3;4;5]
B=[1;2;3]

and I want to plot A vs. B

I know the size are different, therefore I want to set the compensated rows in B equal to 0. 
i.e. B becomes as 
B=[1;2;3;0;0]

Note:
A in this example is larger than B, but I want to do checking to see which one is the largest and the smallest , then do the work

Comment: No need to do this. Just use `plot(A); hold on; plot(B);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
na = numel(A);
nb = numel(B);
A = [A;zeros(nb-na,1)];
B = [B;zeros(na-nb,1)];
```

This will add the appropriate numbers of zeros in the end of the shortest of the row vectors.